# How is entropy related to the amount of energy it would cost in measuring which microstate a system is in given its macrostate?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am trying to understand the connection between entropy and the amount of energy theoretically required to measure the microstate of a system given its macrostate. My understanding is that entropy is related to the number of possible microstates corresponding to a macrostate, but I am unsure about its direct relationship to the energy cost of measuring these microstates.

Can someone please clarify the following:

1. How is entropy conceptually linked to the energy cost associated with measuring the microstate of a system?
2. Is there a quantitative relationship between entropy and the energy required for such measurements?
3. In what ways does the concept of temperature play a role in connecting entropy and energy measurement in statistical mechanics?

Ofcourse I understand that it would be VERY impractical to measure the actual microstate of the system. However I am interested in the theoretical concept of measuring its microstate and how that would relate to the quantity "entropy".

I would appreciate any insights or references that can help me better grasp the underlying physics of this relationship. Thank you!

Comment: The closest thing I am aware of to this is [Landauer's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle). There is no inherent energy cost in making the measurement, but there is one in freeing up the avalible memory

Comment: Which entropy are you interested in? And why do you think that the measurement should cost energy?

Comment: [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/791712/304394)?

Comment: It is about measuring, not Landauer principle